# NameError: name 'x' is not defined - Python

Tags: python

soy nueva en esto de la programación sólo que ya me atoré en un problema, resulta que tengo que hacer un agrupamiento jerárquico y todo va bien hasta que aparece el error:

> File "c:/Users/Itzel/Desktop/python-course/agrupamiento_jerarquico.py", line 46, in 
> distancia_puntos=euclidiana(x, y)
> NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Les presento el código que estoy tratando de implementar

```
import random
import math 
#import bokeh.plotting import figure, show


class Coordenada:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y    

    def coordenadas(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)
    
    def __str__(self):  
        return f'X={self.x} Y={self.y}'


def random_vectors():
    vectors=[]
    for _ in range(8):        
        points=Coordenada(random.randint(1,8), random.randint(1,8)) 
        print(points)
        vectors.append(points)
    return vectors  
    
#euclidiana

def euclidiana(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p2.x-p1.x)**2+(p2.y-p1.y)**2)

p=0

def agrupar():
    for indice in range(len(vectors)):
        valor_actual=vectors[indice]
        cluster=valor_actual.euclidiana(vectors[indice-1])
        agrupar(cluster)
        p+=1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    puntos_aleatorios=random_vectors()
    for _ in range(8):
        distancia_puntos=euclidiana(self.x, self.y)
        print(distancia_puntos)
```

Comment: el error habla de `distancia_puntos=euclidiana(x, y)` y en el código tienes `distancia_puntos=euclidiana(self.x, self.y)`, ¿cuál es la versión real?

Answer (score 0):

El problema en tu código está al momento de ejecutar tu función en `__main__`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    puntos_aleatorios=random_vectors()
    for _ in range(8):
        distancia_puntos=euclidiana(self.x, self.y)
        print(distancia_puntos)
```

Declaras `self.x, self.y` pero para hacer uso de self. este debe estar dentro de alguna clase, cosa que no pasa.

Más bien, lo que supongo quieres, es hacer un `print` a cada punto aleatorio generado en tu función `random_vectors()` por lo que entonces tu función `__main__` debería quedar así

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    puntos_aleatorios=random_vectors() #Generas los puntos aleatorios
    for punto in puntos_aleatorios: #iteras en tus puntos aleatorios y asignas en cada iteración a "punto".
        distancia_puntos=euclidiana(punto.x, punto.y) #Usas "x" y "y" de la variable punto
        print(distancia_puntos)
```